Как в задаче правильно использовать CONVERT_TZ
Я писала
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT((CONVERT_TZ(date, GMT, "Europe/Moscow"), '%d,%m.%Y %H:%i') 
FROM visits 
ORDER BY visits.date;

но запрос не выполняется
Основная проблема с использованием CONVERT_TZ, так как писала запрос по разному : с кавычками, без кавычек ; c другими часовыми поясами ; вообще не опираясь на условие задачи и выдумывая рандомные значения - СУБД все равно ничего не выводит. Может вывести только если вместо строкового формата (где GMT,Europe/Moscow) писать временные значения - тогда результат есть. В общем прошу помочь мне решить эту задачу, третий день идей нет как правильно здесь запрос составить. Понимаю, что возможно и DATE_FORMAT я впихнула не туда, поэтому нужна помощь

Какая СУБД используется и что значит, запрос не выполняется?

В теории, такой запрос должен отработать SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT((CONVERT_TZ(date, 'GMT', 'Europe/Moscow'), '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i') FROM visits ORDER BY visits.date

База данных, это MySQL?

база данных MySql

У вас 3 открывающих скобки и 2 закрывающих
